# jquery - datepicker inside modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, modal-dialog

I have a simple modal form which is triggered by click on the button. In that form there are two datepicker fields. After clicking on the button and open modal form first text field (datepicker) is immediately active and the datepicker calendar is showing.

It looks like that:

[current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYp2p.png)

I don't want first field active, showing calendar from the beginning. Instead of this I want open datepicker after click textfield.
How can I do this?

Here is my simple code:

```html
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="firstDay">Wybierz pierwszy dzień</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstDay" id="firstDay" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <label for="lastDay">Wybierz ostatni dzień</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastDay" id="lastDay" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

```
$(function(){

    $("#dialogForm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width:400,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Anuluj": function(){
                dialog.dialog("close")
            }
        }

    });
    $("#firstDay").datepicker(
        {
            firstDay: 1
        }
    );
    $("#lastDay").datepicker(
        {
            firstDay: 1
        }
    )


    $("#addButton").click(function(){
        $('#dialogForm').dialog('open');
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found couple days ago better solution for that. But unfortunatelly I can't find right now post that helped me.

This is code which makes the input fields are inactive and calendars are hide at the beginning:

```
$(".addButton").click(function(){
    firstDay.datepicker("disable");
    lastDay.datepicker("disable");
    $('#dialogForm').dialog('open');
    firstDay.datepicker("enable");
    lastDay.datepicker("enable");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't tell you for sure without access to your css but I believe this will work for you. In the css of the datepicker, set `display: none;`. Then using js code, set `display: block;` (or whatever you have it as now) when the text field is clicked using the code below.

```
$(document).on('click', 'input', function(){
    $(this).attr("style", "display: block;");
});
```